Trying to adjust screen brightness in the Android system is causing permission issues
I'm trying to adjust the screen brightness on the Android system (Android set-top box, Android TV), but it's not working. I tried using , but it didn't work. I found out that it's possible to adjust the screen brightness from an accessibility service, but I'm not sure how to access it.
in AndroidManifest.xml
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/p05dB .png)
